# How to catch everything after prefix phrase with SED?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

How to catch everything after prefix phrase with sed?

Like here I wished to catch `active/idle`:

```
$ sudo hdparm -C /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 drive state is:  active/idle
$ sudo hdparm -C /dev/sda | sed "s/\s*drive state is:\s+\(.*\)/\1/;tx;d;:x"
```

(empty output follows)

Comment: `awk -F'[: ]' '/state/ {print $NF}'`...

Comment: No need to become root and parse `hdparm` output, use `lsblk -no state /dev/sda`

Comment: that should be `lsblk --nodeps -no state /dev/sda`, otherwise it will also print an empty line for each partition of `/dev/sda`

Answer (score 2):

Redirect stderr to stdout and suppress unwanted parts:

```
sudo hdparm -C /dev/sda 2>&1 | sed -n 's/.*drive state is: *//p'
```